# Is there a way to hide native browser form input autocomplete on form submit with enter key

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, autocomplete

I want to **hide native browser autocomplete** if it has been displayed and the user hits return submitting the form.

If my form looked like this:

```
<form id="test-form" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="autoCompleteTestThang"/>
<button class="btn" type="submit" name="autoCompleteTestThang">Click Mee</button>
```

and my js like this:

```
$('#test-form .btn').click(function(event){
event.preventDefault();

// I'd be an ajax request really
console.log('Event Handled');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7kC83/

The scenario:

- User types in form and native browser autocomplete is populated
- User hits enter to submit the form
- Since this is an ajax call `event.preventDefault();` prevents all default form event handling
- The autocomplete suggestion list is still there and the user has to **click to unfocus** and remove... which I don't want.

Is this possible to hide the autocomplete or am I just going to have to turn it off like:

```
<input type="text" name="noAutoComplete" autocomplete="off" />
```

I know I could do this and add a custom autocomplete. But if I can avoid it I would like the native autocomplete to be used.

Comment: I doubt there's any other way than hiding it entirely. Every browser will do it their own way, and what they do has no representation in the DOM, so you have no "hook" to start manipulating the default behaviour.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought the case would be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using `.blur()` and `.focus()` on the input on submit the autocomplete disappears in the latest version of Chrome. Haven't test it in other browsers though.

```js
$('#test-form .btn').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('Event Handled');
    $('input:first').blur();
    $('input:first').focus();
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7kC83/5/)

Comment: Nice idea! Makes sense that the autocomplete would hook into those events. Seems to work in firefox and that's good enough for me. Will mark as the answer

Comment: Worked great for me! I had an autocomplete that was covering the results under a search box.